# Get image click inside UI table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

i tried to add gesture recognizer in my UIImageView

```
 let rc = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "foo:")
 rc.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
 rc.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
 cell.bar.tag = indexPath.row
 cell.bar.addGestureRecognizer(rc)
```

but didn't call my foo function

```
func foo(sender: UIImageView! ) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("VC", sender: sender)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "VC" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! VC
        vc.item = items[sender.tag]
    }
}
```

Comment: try add `cell.bar.userInteractionEnabled = true`. By default it is `false` for `UIImageView`.

Comment: but I have new problem it is when i want to get items xcode display errors like that "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" reason is sender.tag is nil. How to solve that problem? @rkyr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as I mentioned before your problem is `UIImageView` by default has property `userInteractionEnabled` set to `false`. You can change this in you storyboard, or add line `cell.bar.userInteractionEnabled = true`.

Next your problem is in your `foo:` method implementation: you specify sender as `UIImageView!`, but it should be `UITapGestureRecognizer`. This is why it crashes - it cannot be `UIImageView`, so when it unwraps (`!`) it is `nil`.

Solution: change your `foo` method declaration to `foo(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)`. If you need access your `imageView` inside this method you can use code below:

```
if let imageView = recognizer.view as? UIImageView {
  ...
}
```

or with new `guard` keyword (Swift 2.0)

```
guard let imageView = recognizer.view as? UIImageView
else { return }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can change**

```
foo(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

}
```